# Can I use my hotspot on my phone for Airplay?

Tags: wifi, tethering

I have an iPhone 5S and I am looking for a way to mirror my screen to the TV. I was wondering if I could use the hotspot on the phone to connect my PC (on the TV) and the iPhone, to airplay to the PC, which mirrors to the TV. Thank you!

Comment: It's pretty confusing what you're asking, but I'll try my best to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Though info on the topic seems somewhat sparse, a few threads [like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/25kaau/airplay_over_personal_hotspot/) and [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20120328105542460) seem to indicate that using a hotspot works as a viable Wi-Fi network for AirPlay (as long as, of course, you connect both the iPhone and the computer to the hotspot.) However, if you've already got a Wi-Fi network, you'd probably be better off using that instead of a hotspot.

Since your PC doesn't support AirPlay off the bat, you'd need some sort of software like [AirServer](https://www.airserver.com) to make it a valid AirPlay device. From there, simply connect it to your TV and AirPlay from your phone to the PC.

However, if you do have an Apple TV, a feature called [Peer-to-Peer](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204289) AirPlay is available that will let you AirPlay from your iPhone to your Apple TV without a formal Wi-Fi network, circumventing the need to create a hotspot. Just turn on Bluetooth and Wi-Fi on both devices and it should work. Note, however, that [AirServer doesn't support this](https://www.airserver.com/Compare), so you would need an Apple TV.